# How to convert 1,2,3 to '1','2','3' in php

Tags: php, explode, implode

I want to convert 1,2,3 to '1','2','3' in PHP, I tried using impode but its giving like '1,2,3' but I want single quotes to individual numbers. 
Please Help,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = '1,2,3';

$parts = explode(',', $string);

$string = "'".implode("','", $parts)."'";

echo $string; // is now '1','2','3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think string replace is faster here:

```
$string = '1,2,3';
$string = "'".str_replace(',', "','", $string)."'";
```

Comment: I really think you should use str_replace, because that's exactly what you need. All other solutions are more expensive work-arounds

Answer (score 1):

There's also an alternative for this using `preg_replace` like as

```
echo preg_replace("/(\d+)/","'$1'",$str);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/459093)